# C# Owin OAuth2 - Provider login redirect goes to incorrect base URL

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, owin

I have a C# application running as the backend API for a website. 
It is using `Microsoft.Owin` for external social logins. Everything works fine deployed on localhost. In production, when the backend endpoint is requested for `ExternalLogin` via popup window with url like:

"mywebsiteurl/api//ExternalLogin?provider=Google&redirect_uri=...", instead of redirecting the URL to something like:

"**https://accounts.google.com**/o/oauth2/auth?..." (in the case of Google+),

it redirects to: "**mywebsiteurl**/o/oauth2/auth?..."

which obviously returns a 404.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: i thinks you should show your code here

Comment: This doesn't seem to be happening in my code though. The middleware takes over and redirects to this url. Everything works fine on local deployment, just not in production. The only line that might be relevant in my code: 
`_request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(_loginProvider);`
This is where the owin middleware takes over.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We seem to have a similar problem in production.